# Mediaquery makes navbar unresponsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I've been working on a **MVC** web application. So far everything has worked out fine, expect that one single thing. Basically, my problem is, that while attempting and succeeding in making the toggle button of my `navbar` disappear when the site has a certain size, my `navbar` is no longer responsive, as it no longer adapts its size to the screen.

Here is my entire `button` and `navbar` code:

**Here is my environment:**

```
     <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </environment>
    <environment names="Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
until here

            <div class="navbar-header navbarnone">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler-icon navbarbutton" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="X" asp-action="Index">X</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="x" asp-action="Index">x</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" asp-controller="X" asp-action="Privacy">x</a>
                    </li>
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**And here the CSS code for the `mediaquery`:**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbarnone {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using a framework or library, you need to tag that. You are using non-standard HTML that needs to be identified.

Comment: working fine :- https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/t8Le7asd/

Comment: This still doesn't make sense. What is that non-standard HTML?

Comment: @Rob It's Bootstrap. It works just like HTML.

Comment: check this with your HTML https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar

Answer (score 0):

Because others might have the same problem, I'll post the answer I found for myself:

There's a line that's missing in the code. A meta line.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

For some reason this meta tag prevents Google Chrome from screwing their dev tools up.